# After HR I get this error: com.google.process.gapps was interrupted

Tags: crashes, google-play-services, google-apps, force-close

Lately I have had some problems with my Asus Zenpad 7, a strange message:

> "Unfortunatly com.google.process.gapps was interrupted"

which doesn't stop appearing, my use of the tablet is now limited to what I can do in the miliseconds I have between messages.

I tried many things such as reinstalling Play Store and Google Services, cleaning cache and reactivating the download manager but nothing worked.

Therefore I decided to hard reset, in fact I clicked two options on the Restore Mode of Zenpad 7: Wipe Cache and Wipe Data/Factory Reset, but the messages keep appearing.

I have the tablet rooted using KingRoot, and it may be something I have done while playing with Play Store patches (don't know what, I was just seeing what Lucky Patcher had).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Tried flashing the firmware? I think something got corrupted flashing should solve this

Comment: You are welcom. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, sorry to the moderators if they have to do something but as I don't know how to finish this things when the answer is in the comments just to say I did like @esQmo_ said and flashed the firmware from asus page and everything ok.